# Let X represent the difference between the number of HEADS and the number of CROSSES obtained when a coin is flipped five times.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ represent the difference between the number of HEADS and the number of CROSSES obtained when a coin is flipped five times. What are the possible values of $X$? What are the probabilities associated with the values that $X$ can take? Plot the density function and the distribution function.

When flipping a coin we have $2$ possible outcomes, so when flipping the coin five times, there are $2^5=32$ outcomes.

Now, we can do the following:

$5$ HEADS, $0$ CROSSES - $X=5$

$4$ HEADS, $1$ CROSSES - $X=3$

$3$ HEADS, $2$ CROSSES - $X=1$

$2$ HEADS, $3$ CROSSES - $X=-1$

$1$ HEADS, $4$ CROSSES - $X=-3$

$0$ HEADS, $5$ CROSSES - $X=-5$

I don't know if what I am doing is right. And I don't know how to calculate the probability.

I don't think it's that easy to make a binormal distribution, because $X$ represents the difference between the number of heads and tails....

How could $X$ be interpreted?

Comment: Where are you finding difficulty?  The number of heads out of $5$ tosses is a routine binomial disribution.

Comment: It's a new topic, and I understand it....

Comment: Well, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) is a routine discussion of the binomial distribution.  That should be enough to solve this problem.

Comment: Let $Y$ be the count for heads, so $5-Y$ is the count for tails.  Then $X=2Y-5$ is the difference between the former and latter. Now use that $Y$ is binomially distributed, to find $\mathsf P(X=x)$.

Comment: Notice that $X = 3$ when exactly four heads are tossed in five trials.  In how many ways can that occur?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig $P(X=3)=5/16$?

Comment: Remember that there are $2^5 = 32$ possible outcomes.  Since there are $\binom{5}{4} = 5$ outcomes in which there are four heads and one tail, $\Pr(X = 3) = \frac{5}{32}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Right, I thought it was 3 heads $5!/3!2!$. Sorry.

Comment: Are the values for X that I have proposed correct?

Comment: If there are exactly three heads, then there must be two tails, so your calculation tells you that $\Pr(X = 1) = \frac{10}{32} = \frac{5}{16}$.  Yes, you have determined the correct values for $X$.  It looks like you should be able to find the probability of each possible value of $X$ at this point.

Comment: Thank you... thank you very much